# How do I modify the Damerau-Levenshtein algorithm, such that it also includes the start index, and the end index of the larger substring?

Tags: ruby, algorithm, levenshtein-distance

Here is my code:

```
#http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Damerau%E2%80%93Levenshtein_distance
# used for fuzzy matching of two strings
# for indexing, seq2 must be the parent string
  def dameraulevenshtein(seq1, seq2)
      oneago = nil
      min = 100000000000 #index
      max = 0 #index
      thisrow = (1..seq2.size).to_a + [0]
      seq1.size.times do |x|
          twoago, oneago, thisrow = oneago, thisrow, [0] * seq2.size + [x + 1]
          seq2.size.times do |y|
              delcost = oneago[y] + 1
              addcost = thisrow[y - 1] + 1
              subcost = oneago[y - 1] + ((seq1[x] != seq2[y]) ? 1 : 0)
              thisrow[y] = [delcost, addcost, subcost].min
              if (x > 0 and y > 0 and seq1[x] == seq2[y-1] and seq1[x-1] == seq2[y] and seq1[x] != seq2[y])
                  thisrow[y] = [thisrow[y], twoago[y-2] + 1].min
              end
          end
      end
      return thisrow[seq2.size - 1], min, max
  end
```

there has to be someway to get the starting and ending  index of substring, seq1, withing parent string, seq2, right?

I'm not entirely sure how this  algorithm works, even after reading the wiki article on it. I mean, I understand the highest level explanation, as it finds the insertion, deletion, and transposition difference (the lines in the second loop).. but beyond that. I'm a bit lost.

Here is an example of something that I wan to be able to do with this (^):

```
substring = "hello there"
search_string = "uh,\n\thello\n\t there"
```

the indexes should be:

```
  start: 5
  end:   18 (last char of string)
```

Ideally, the search_string will never be modified. But, I guess I could take out all the white space characters (since there are only.. 3? \n \r and \t) store the indexes of each white space character, get the indexes of my substring, and then re-add in the white space characters, making sure to compensate the substring's indexes as I offset them with the white space characters that were originally in there in the first place. -- but if this could all be done in the same method, that would be amazing, as the algorithm is already O(n^2).. =(

At some point, I'd like to only allow white space characters to split up the substring (s1).. but one thing at a time

Comment: Since it's using fuzzy matching, I'm not sure how you would define the starting and ending index of the first string.  Can you give an example of a pair of strings and what you are looking for?

Comment: just added to my question. thanks! =D

Answer (score 1):

I don't think this algorithm is the right choice for what you want to do.  The algorithm is simply calculating the distance between two strings in terms of the number of modifications you need to make to turn one string into another.  If we rename your function to dlmatch for brevity and only return the distance, then we have:

```
dlmatch("hello there", "uh, \n\thello\n\t there"
=> 7
```

meaning that you can convert one string into the other in 7 steps (effectively by removing seven characters from the second).  The problem is that 7 steps is a pretty big difference:

```
dlmatch("hello there", "panda here"
=> 6
```

This would actually imply that "hello there" and "panda here" are closer matches than the first example.

If what you are trying to do is "find a substring that mostly matches", I think you are stuck with an O(n^3) algorithm as you feed the first string to a series of substrings of the second string, and then selecting the substring that provides you the closest match.

Alternatively, you may be better off trying to do pre-processing on the search string and then doing regexp matching with the substring.  For example, you could strip off all special characters and then build a regexp that looks for words in the substring that are case insensitive and can have any amount of whitespace between them.

Comment: Building on what you said :
`"uh,\n\thello\n\t there".match(/(hello)\s*(there)/) do |m|
  p m.begin(1) #=> 5
  p m.end(2)   #=> 18
end`

Comment: if you take the distance and then see if that == the difference in length between the two strings, you can assume one is in the other

Comment: That's true, but then you might as well just do substring searches which will be much faster (O(n)) rather than using a difference function.